# Change color of the footer background in Css and Html

Tags: html, css, colors

This is the footer part code of my project

HTML Code:

```
<footer>
        <div class = "footer_container">
            <div class = "copyright">
                <h1>Urban Clothes | Copyright &copy; 2015-2020 </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

CSS Code:

```
.footer_container{
    background-color: white;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
}
```

Body Code:

```
body{
    background-color: #24252A;
}
```

I am unable to change the background colour of my footer container. I changed the background colour of my body but the footer background colour is not changing.

Comment: your code works well here. perhaps you have duplicated the `.footer_container` class somewhere in your css, and this class overrides the class you need. you also specified white for the background, and perhaps that is why it seems to you that the color is not accepted

Comment: `body` and `.footer_container`  are 2 different selectors with 2 different `background-color` , if you want to modify `.footer_container` , you need to use this selector, not `body`. If you want both the same color, usse the same background-color for both selector. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info

Comment: You code works, try to refresh

Comment: I forgot to link the CSS file to the HTML file. Sorry guys, it was a silly mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

```
       .footer_container {
        background: red;
        height: 400px;
        border: 2px solid lightblue;
    }
```

try to do shift refresh for the page ur working it will work, try with these code

Comment: I forgot to link the CSS file to the HTML file. Sorry guys, it was a silly mistake :)

Answer (score -1):

Your code works for me. Maybe your browser has cached the style change your browser and try again or clear your web cache and then try again

Answer (score -2):

You have a `background-color: white;` in your `.footer_container`, if you want for footer to have the color of body just don't give it a `background-color: white;` or you can give it `background-color: transparent;`

Answer (score -2):

you can add !important, but it may affect other part of code if you have used same class name for other elements

```
.footer_container{
    background-color: white!important;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
}
```